# TextView wont display number longer than 9 characters

Tags: android, eclipse, string, textview

```
            double largeNumber = 2351778 * finalSeconds;
            mediaViewLeft03.setText(String.format("%.0f", largeNumber));
```

Currently the text view will only display the last 9 characters of largeNumber even though it is between 11-12 characters long. I've search around but can't find any solutions. Also how do I get it to display the commas ie. 123,456,789,123 instead of the current 9 characters being 123456789.

Comment: did you go into your xml and make the TextView larger?

Comment: is the textview layout_width=wrap_content?

Comment: There is plenty of room left in the text view for the number to be displayed, its set to fill_parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want any digits after the decimal why don't you try using `"%,d"` for your format and a `long` for your argument. This will give you the commas too.  See [`Formatter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html).

Comment: @SpunkTrumpet also you may try `(""+longValue)`, its String also, or even yours double with ""+ (there won't be comas or dots, Formatter as above is good solution